# strategies to encode integer arrays into images

Tags: java, arrays, image

I am thinking about embedding arbitrary integer array data into an image file.

I am curious to see what my data looks like :-)

Here are the questions which come to mind:

- What are the permissible integer ranges for conversion? (My integers are between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE).

  - How do I need to handle 0 to Integer.MAX_VALUE *to* 8-bit ARGB integer ranges?
- Which lossless image format (png?)
- Does such a library already exist?
- I need to decode the data too. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's rather simple, since when you deal with a BufferedImage in Java, each pixel is stored (or at least, accessed) as an int natively. The full range of values is available, if your image is ARGB (32-bits). Any lossless image format will do.

```
int[] array = new int[100];
    final BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(array.length, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        im.setRGB(i, 0, array[i]); // NOTE: this is probably optimizable
```

Comment: While ARGB stores int values losslessly, it is worth emphasizing that image types which do not use 32 bits will truncate the data given in `setRGB`, so the data returned by `getRGB` could be a different int.  So be sure to use ARGB (as @Bart and OP suggest)